# datatable listing issue of sort order

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, datatable

I am using datatable. I am using the following mysql query

```
$sql="select * from table ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(  `pdate` ,  '%d/%m/%Y' ) desc";
```

But this ORDER BY Date is not working. It is not listing the data in the order of pdate desc. It is listing data randomly

pdate is storing in the table in the format '29/09/2016'

when I am running this query in database table it is listing properly but in datatable sorting order is not correct.it is listing in the ascending order of first column in the datatable listing

```
sql query
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `pdate` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `test`
--

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `name`, `pdate`) VALUES
(1, 'a', '29/09/2016'),
(2, 'b', '29/09/2015'),
(3, 'c', '29/02/2016'),
(4, 'd', '22/05/2016'),
(5, 'e', '27/06/2015');
```

table display

```
    <script src="jstables/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script src="jstables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="jstables/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="jstables/buttons.flash.js"></script>
<script src="jstables/jszip.js"></script>
<script src="jstables/pdfmake.js"></script>
<script src="jstables/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="jstables/buttons.html5.js"></script>
<script src="jstables/buttons.print.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="csstables/jquery.dataTables.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="csstables/buttons.dataTables.css" />
$querystring="select * from test ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(  `pdate` ,  '%d/%m/%Y' ) desc";
$sql=mysql_query($querystring);
<table id="example" border="1" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><thead>
<tr><th>aws</th><th>dd</th></tr></thead><tbody>
<?php
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
?>
<tr><td><?php echo $res['name'];?></td><td><?php echo $res['pdate'];?></td></tr>
<?php
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {

        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
} );
    </script>
```

Comment: are you checked database values and you pass the pdate values in same format?

Comment: yes in db it is storing in this format eg. 29/09/2016. it is working properly when i run this sql in my phpmyadmin

Comment: what you get current result?

Comment: currently while i am listing it in datatable it is not listing in the desc order of pdate

Comment: its working post your database infomations

Comment: i am getting this result `id` as `1` , `name` as `a` and `date` as `29/09/2016` in table format

Comment: now whats your problem?

Comment: did you try it in bootstrap? did u include datatable js and css? did u see any export buttons above listing?

Comment: in the normal case it will work. but for datatable (also with export option in datatable) it is not working

Comment: i never test with `bootstrap` and i never add any other files

Answer (score 2):

try add order parameter after your dom code on datatable like this :

```
$('#table').DataTable({
    "order": [[2, "desc"]] //"2" is my date array position
    .......
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$sql="select * from table where name='$name' ORDER BY `pdate` desc";
```

Comment: tried but listing order is not in the desc order of pdate

Comment: in which order result is return?

Comment: in the ascending order order of first column in the datatable listing

Answer (score 0):

You are storing date in varchar datatype column.

so when you do order by it will treat as text not date.

you need to type casting for that

```
select * from table ORDER BY CAST(`pdate` AS DATE) desc
```

Reference
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html